# android app for different end user

Tags: android

This may be as simple as for your knowledge. But I don't know how to search and get.

Now I've developed one android app with sqlite. Using this app, from my device only I can create and do insert and update the data as admin and user. I want to develop my app should be accessed by many user from different mobile and they should be update their detail. What are all the things I should know and How to do ?

Please help me out.

Comment: you just need to maintain your primary key which is user id. You can assign every user a unique key and based on that you can maintain their details.. :)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are new to this. Since your app is already completed and I am assuming it is working I would suggest reading up on the following things and you will need to make a few decisions also.

I believe that the LAMP stack would be best for you unless you have .NET experience, you should go read up on:

- [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/)
- [pHp](http://php.net/)
- RESTful web services and what they do [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671118/what-exactly-is-restful-programming)
- How to [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) works
- How to run [backgroud services](http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html)

MySQL will be used to store your data in the cloud

pHp will be the server side language with which you access and query your database and control the data being written to it

RESTful will be the way you implement your pHp functions and how you will return data and process requests to your service

AsyncTask will allow you to run background processes in Android, it is important to remember never to run a long running action in the main UI thread, thus we use AsyncTask to accomplish the multithreading

I suggest background services since you already have a functioning app with a local sql database, the background services can then be used to keep your app synced with the database in the cloud, that way when a new user accesses your app on a different device that he/she normally uses his/her data will be available on the new device.